# firebase div Id is not showing onclick

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I iterated through firebase data to populate this cards using the code below

```
function retrieveProductList(data) {

var container = document.getElementById('listing_gallery');
container.innerHTML = '';

data.forEach(function(listingSnap) { // loop over all jobs
    var key = listingSnap.key;
    var Items = listingSnap.val();
    var productCard = `                  
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card" onclick="showproductpage();" id="${key}">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="${Items.ProductImageUrl}" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Firebase</h4>
                            <p class="card-title">${Items.NSN}</p>

                            <p class="card-text" id="product_price">${Items.Price}</p>
                            <a href="#" data-name="Lemon" data-price="5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary" onclick="Add_item_to_cart();">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
                    `;
    container.innerHTML += productCard;


})
}
```

the function works and displayed all the desired info. What I am having problem with is how to get each cards id in the console when I click on it. I tried with this function

```
 function showproductpage(){

 console.log("Product clicked")

 console.log(this.id);
 }
```

the function only displayed "Product clicked" in console and the id is identified as undefined. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it to show the card firebase id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send reference to DOM element as parameter to `showproductpage()` function, so the updated call becomes `showproductpage(this)`. Sample below:

```js
function showproductpage(element) {
  console.log(element.id)
}
```

```html
<div class="card" onclick="showproductpage(this);" id="card_01">Click</div>
```

```js
function showproductpage() {
    console.log(event.target.id)
}
```

```html
<div class="card" onclick="showproductpage();" id="card_01">Click</div>
```

Comment: I have used the previous method before and it worked any idea why it is not working for this scenerio

Comment: I have created second snippet above. In the second one, you can call `event.target` to get handle to DOM element that has been clicked. Then get `id` from that target.